# Basic Authentication at Grizzly Server

Tags: java, jersey, basic-authentication, grizzly

I am using Jersey Grizzly and want to implement Basic Authentication to Grizzly. I create my grizzly server as follows:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.abc.de");
GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
```

at another class I have something like:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/description")
public String getDescription() {
    String description = "probeDescription";
    return description;
}
```

I don't know the difference and main concepts of jersey and grizzly. What jersey can't do that grizzly can. However I want that if a user wants to get description it should pass the basic authentication.

Any ideas about how can I implement it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I followed that example: http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/show/trunk/jersey/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly?rev=5752 and it works.

Comment: This link is dead. Please post content instead of links.