# Where to hook up authentication in Grizzly?

Tags: http, authentication, grizzly

I'm using a Grizzly `HttpServer` which has two `HttpHandler` instances registered:

- under `/api/*` there is an Jersey REST - style application offering the API of the product, and
- under `/*` there is an `StaticHttpHandler` which serves static HTML / JavaScript content (which, among other things, talks to the API under `/api/`

For authentication I'm currently securing *only*  the API using a Jersey `ContainerRequestFilter` implementing HTTP Basic Auth, which looks quite similar to what is presented in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608162/basic-http-authentication-with-jersey-grizzly).

But as requirements changed, now I'd like to require authentication for *all* requests hitting the server. So I'd like to move the authentication one level up, from Jersey to Grizzly. Unfortunately, I'm completely lost figuring out where I can hook up a "request filter" (or whatever it is called) in Grizzly. Can someone point me to the relevant API to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would leverage the Grizzly embedded Servlet support.

This of course would mean you'd need to do a little work to migrate your current `HttpHandler` logic over to `Servlet`s - but that really shouldn't be too difficult as the `HttpHandler` API is very similar.

I'll give some high level points on doing this.

```java
HttpServer server = HttpServlet.createSimpleServer(<docroot>, <host>, <port>);
// use "" for <context path> if you want the context path to be /
WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext(<logical name>, <context path>);

// do some Jersey initialization here

// Register the Servlets that were converted from HttpHandlers
ServletRegistration s1 = ctx.addServlet(<servlet name>, <Servlet instance or class name>);
s1.addMapping(<url pattern for s1>);
// Repeat for other Servlets ...

// Now for the authentication Filter ...
FilterRegistration reg = ctx.addFilter(<filter name>, <filter instance or class name>);
// Apply this filter to all requests
reg.addMapping(null, "/*");

// do any other additional initialization work ...

// "Deploy" ctx to the server.
ctx.deploy(server);

// start the server and test ...
```

NOTE: The dynamic registration of Servlets and Filters is based off the Servlet 3.0 API, so if you want information on how to deal with Servlet listeners, init parameters, etc., I would recommend reviewing the Servlet 3.0 javadocs.

NOTE2: The Grizzly Servlet implementation is not 100% compatible with the Servlet specification.  It doesn't support standard Servlet annotations, or deployment of traditional Servlet web application archive deployment.

Lastly, there are examples of using the embedded Servlet API [here](https://github.com/GrizzlyNIO/grizzly-mirror/tree/2.3.x/modules/http-servlet/src/test/java/org/glassfish/grizzly/servlet)

Answer (score 0):

The "hookup" part can be done using a HttpServerProbe (tested with Grizzly 2.3.5):

```
srv.getServerConfiguration().getMonitoringConfig().getWebServerConfig()
.addProbes(new HttpServerProbe.Adapter() {
   @Override
   public void onRequestReceiveEvent(HttpServerFilter filter,
     Connection connection, Request request) {
     ...
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestCompleteEvent(HttpServerFilter filter,
  Connection connection, Response response) {
   }
 });
```

For the "linking" to the ContainerRequestFilter you might want to have a look at my question:
[UnsupportedOperationException getUserPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105005/unsupportedoperationexception-getuserprincipal)