# UnsupportedOperationException getUserPrincipal

Tags: java, authentication, jersey, grizzly

I have created a ContainerRequestfilter and successfully made it trigger.
Now I'd like acccess the UserPrincipal I have set before in a grizzly HttpServerProbe like this:

```
import com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest;

@Override
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
  Principal principal=req.getUserPrincipal();
}
```

Instead a "UnsupportedOperationException" is thrown. It looks like the ContainerRequest does not pick up the UserPrincipal from the modified request.

The modification is done via

```
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;

...

public void onRequestReceiveEvent(
  HttpServerFilter filter,Connection connection, Request request) {
  Principal principal=getPrincipalFromRequest(request);
  request.setUserPrincipal(principal);
}
```

The issue is how to to transport the Principal information from the HttpServerProbe to
the ContainerRequestFilter. The org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request has the security
information (in this case SSL Client certificate information) while the com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest initially does not provide it.

Unfortunately I have also not found a way to set the SecurityContext in the HttpServerProbe. In
the ContainerRequestFilter i could do it but the necessary Principal information is not available as I would have expected.

I am using Jersey 1.17 and Grizzly 2.3.5

the following links where all somewhat related to the issue, but none was giving a clue
what may be the reason for the above error:

http://www.solutionoferror.com/java/use-containerrequestfilter-in-jersey-without-web-xml-79849.asp

[Jersey ContainerRequestFilter not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300218/jersey-containerrequestfilter-not-triggered)

http://subversion.jfrog.org/artifactory/public/tags/2.1.0/rest/src/main/java/org/artifactory/rest/common/RestAuthenticationFilter.java

http://sites.gbif.org/common-resources/gbif-common-ws/xref/org/gbif/ws/server/filter/AuthFilter.html

http://2rdscreenretargeting.blogspot.de/2012/06/secure-jersey-with-oauth2.html

What needs to be done to access the principal / set the security context with the principal in a way that HttpServerProbe and ContainerRequestFilter cooperate in assembling this info ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jersey/JAX-RS expects [SecurityContext](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) to be set before you can retrieve any information about principal, user roles etc. Usually, in Jersey, this is done by dedicated [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.17/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html). Take a look at the sample filter from one of our samples: [SecurityFilter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/blob/master/samples/https-clientserver-grizzly/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/https_grizzly/auth/SecurityFilter.java#L61).

After this, you can inject `SecurityContext` (using `@Context`) into your resources or other providers such as filters. You can then also call `containerRequest.getUserPrincipal()` without getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

#### EDIT 1

If you need to obtain `Principal` object in grizzly level you can inject the current `Request` into your filter and then retrieve the value in `filter` method.

```
@Context
private ThreadLocal<Request> request;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I have modified the question to be more clear. I would happily set the SecurityContext if i could only get the Principal information that is already available over to the ContainerRequestFilter

Comment: I have worked around the issue now by creating a PrincipalCache - the HttpUnitServerProbe adds the Principal by it's name into the cache and adds a header info to the request. This way the ContainerRequestFilter can pick up the Principal from the cache by using the information from the modified request header. Given the example you mentioned the BasicAuth is also possible when there is no principal info in the Cache.